# array of images into cylinder?

Tags: iphone, ios

I've got my code here for my array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < imgCount; i++) {
        // Load image from the bundle

        NSString * fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Image-%d", i];
        NSString * filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: fileName ofType: @"jpeg"];

        UIImage * img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: filePath];
```

Is it possible to make my array into a cylinder type or calayer with transition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried studying this: [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)

and this also, it has a layer transition example : [CA360](https://github.com/neror/CA360)

Hope this could help to anyone.